# Create multiple virtual hosts (Linux Mint 18.2)

Tags: linux-mint, apache-virtualhost

I have vhost with following conf (**localhost.conf**) file (this needs to be like this in order for an app I am working on to work properly (please don't ask why I didn't make the setup)):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@wp.dev
    ServerName localhost
    #ServerAlias www.wp.dev
    DocumentRoot /home/sasha/Documents/Scopic/STS/project/timesheetapprovalsgit/timesheet_ui/web

    <Directory /home/sasha/Documents/Scopic/STS/project/timesheetapprovalsgit/timesheet_ui>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I am trying to add new vhost (**prst.conf**):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@prst.app
    ServerName prst.app
    ServerAlias www.prst.app
    DocumentRoot /home/sasha/Documents/Scopic/PerformanceReview/project/performance-review-status-tracking/public

    <Directory /home/sasha/Documents/Scopic/PerformanceReview/project/performance-review-status-tracking>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   www.prst.app
```

The main issue I have at the moment is that whenever I go to **www.prst.app**, I am redirected to the localhost. Does anyone have an idea what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server name is defined as:

```
  ServerName prst.app
```

so define in `/etc/hosts` prst.app not www.prst.app

```
127.0.0.1   prst.app
```

To access www.prst.app create new virtual host and new record in `/etc/hosts`